# How to make vocal growl less airy?

Tags: technique, voice, bass-voice

I can growl (Tim Foust/Avi Kaplan-style), but my low growl notes sound very airy.

Is there any way to get them to sound "fuller"? Or at least minimise the wind-like noise?

Comment: Can you give us an audio clip of what you're going for?  When I read "growl" I think of death metal, but you're referencing one country and one a capella singer, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Sarkreth I'm pretty sure this one's a bass technique. It's in some of those vocal range videos, it's their lowest notes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3i1D22zszM

Answer (score 1):

To minimise wind noise a few things come to mind.

1. Use a pop shield (however I imagine you are already).
2. Place the microphone off axis from the vocalist so that the "wind" doesn't directly fall onto the diaphragm of the microphone.

It could be down to the type of microphone you are using, the frequency response and acoustics.

Generally compression, EQ (away form the high end for the growl possibly), de-essers, noise gates and any typical type of processing would help, particularly for "fullness ".A Focusrite Voicemaster is a good bit of kit to look at which has all the vocal processing things you may consider to beef up the sound.

Hope this helps!